# How can I retrieve transaction history of an address with my own ether node?

Tags: transactions

Etherscan shows transaction history of my address. How can I get the history without using Etherscan? I have my own ether node, geth server. Do I have to install anything tools?

https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x5DBB9793537515398A1176d365b636A5321D9e39

---

Update 1

Seems using Block explorer is a good way.

e.g. etherchain-light
https://github.com/gobitfly/etherchain-light